# Unit polynomial vector fields on the sphere

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Let $\mathbb{S}^3 \subset \mathbb{R}^4$ be the unit $3$-sphere. Is there a classification available for $3$-homogeneous polynomial, unit norm, vector fields on $\mathbb{S}^3$?

More explicitly, a $3$-homogeneous polynomial vector field on $\mathbb{S}^3$ is a restriction to $\mathbb{S}^3$ of a map $P:x \mapsto (P_1, P_2, P_3, P_4)$, where each $P_i$ is a homogeneous polynomial of degree $3$ in $x = (x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4)$, such that $\sum_{i = 1}^4 x_iP_i = 0$. It is of unit norm if $P$ maps $\mathbb{S}^3$ to $\mathbb{S}^3$ or equivalently if $P_1^2 + P_2^2 + P_3^2 + P_4^2 = 1$ when $|x| = 1$ (equivalently just $P_1^2 + P_2^2 + P_3^2 + P_4^2 = (x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2 + x_4^2)^3$).

---

Some obervations:

- Any unit vector field has topological degree $1$ as a map $\mathbb{S}^3 \to \mathbb{S}^3$.
- If $J$ is a complex structure on $\mathbb{R}^4$ (i.e. $J^2 = -1$ and $J^T = -J$), then $x \mapsto Jx$ is a unit norm vector field on $\mathbb{S}^3$.
- There's a way to construct $3$-homogeneous vector fields. Given any unit vector fields $F$ and $G$ on $\mathbb{S}^3$, we may take:
  $$H:= -F.|x|^2 + 2\langle{F, G}\rangle.G$$
  It is easy to see that $H$ is also a unit vector field (this construction is due to Wood); also if $F$ and $G$ are $1$-homogeneous, then $H$ is $3$-homogeneous. Choosing $F = J_Fx$ and $G = J_Gx$ for some complex structures $J_F, J_G$, it easy to see that we may create $H$ to be purely of degree $3$ (i.e. it is not a multiple of $|x|^2$ and another linear unit vector field). **Is this the only way to create such vector fields?**
- There are other examples. Consider the Hopf map $\mathbb{S}^3 \to \mathbb{S}^2$ given by
  $$(w, x, y, z) \mapsto (2(wy + xz), 2(xy - wz), -w^2-x^2+y^2 + z^2)$$
  It is easy to see that $\mathcal{H} = 2(wy + xz) V_1 + 2(xy - wz) V_2 + (-w^2 -x^2 + y^2 + z^2) V_3$, where $V_1 = Ix$, $V_2 = Jx$, $V_3 = Kx$ are pointwise orthonormal ($I, J, K$ are the quaternion matrices), satisfies the assumptions and cannot be reduced to a linear vector field. Moreover any quadratic map $\mathbb{S}^3 \to \mathbb{S}^2$ reduces to the Hopf map by rotations (by a book from Eells and Rotta).
- Solutions of the Cartan-Munzner equations $|\nabla F|^2 = |x|^6$ give *maps* $\mathbb{S}^3 \to \mathbb{S}^3$.
- See [Homogeneous polynomial vector fields tangent to the unit sphere](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/195249/homogeneous-polynomial-vector-fields-tangent-to-the-unit-sphere) for the computation of the dimension of the space of homogeneous polynomial vector fields, which are not necessarily unit (in our case it is **$45$**).
- I am also interested in the classification of unit $3$-homogeneous vector fields on other odd unit spheres, but $\mathbb{S}^3$ might be the simplest non-trivial case.
- update: a small computation shows that the degree $1$ part $H_1$ (i.e. writing $H = H_1. |x|^2 + H_3$, where $H_{1, 3}$ are harmonic and $1,3$-homogeneous) of the Wood's vector field $H$ (see third point), necessarily comes from an anti-symmetric matrix; on the other hand the degree $1$ part the Hopf vector field $\mathcal{H}$ is not anti-symmetric. Hence $\mathcal{H}$ does **not** come from Wood's construction. This indicates that the spheres with Hopf fibrations $\mathbb{S}^3, \mathbb{S}^7, \mathbb{S}^{15}$ could be special, while in all other cases the vector fields should come from Wood's construction.